# PHP - $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] inconsistent

Tags: php, xampp

`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` sometimes returns 10.0.0.2 and sometimes a hex value like fe80::d7c:2a15:b162:81c1 during the same session. Why is this happening? I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: It looks like you are returning the mac address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use the DNS name to access your server. As such, you might get either an A or an AAAA record for the DNS name. Which means, one time you access via IPv4 and the other via IPv6 (fe80::d7c:2a15:b162:81c1 is an IPv6-address).

Comment: Ok, but why is this happening, I mean why is it inconsistent and how can I make it behave the same way all the time (I don't care if it's IPv4 or IPv6 just as long as it stays the same in the same session)

Comment: You can disable either IPv6 or IPv4 on either your client or your server machine. You could also remove either the A or the AAAA entry from your DNS. I don't know your exact scenario so you'd have to tell me more about that.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out earlier, those hex values are ipv6 addresses..you need to change your code to adapt to both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses if it depends on `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`